# Analysis of simple pulley system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I have some questions about the motion of the simple pulley system illustrated in the book Machinae novae. Are the following conclusion about the system correct?

1. Since the length of the rope is constant, the carriage will move to right by the same amount, passenger is pulling the rope to the left, irrespective of the mass of carriage?
2. The carriage will never toppel, irrespective of the amount of pulling force or location of the carriage along the path. Basically, only the angle of the pulling rope will change but the angle of rope supporting the carriage will always be perpendicular.
3. The mass of the carriage will be limited by the breaking strength of the rope?

[image]